# How do I simulate mouse clicking in VBScript?

Tags: vbscript, automation, click, mouse, minecraft

I'm trying to create a VBScript to automate two left clicks and a right click with a 0.2 seconds delay between them to automate Minecraft farming.
I used this code but it gives me an error on line 5:

```
Dim x
Set x = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Do
    WScript.Sleep 200
    x.SendKeys "{CLICK LEFT,960,540}"
    WScript.Sleep 200
    x.SendKeys "{CLICK LEFT,960,540}"
    WScript.Sleep 200
    x.SendKeys "{CLICK RIGHT,960,540}"
Loop
```

What could I have done wrong?

Comment: sendkeys cannot send mouse clicks.

Comment: well how do i do it

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where you got that syntax from, but the WScript.Shell [SendKeys method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8c6yea83%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) doesn't have any way to send mouse clicks.

There's no way built into VBScript to simulate mouse clicks. You either need to find or create a COM Component that does so, or use some other language for the automation you're trying to do.